# jQuery UI Slider gets locked when both handles are set to max value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

When I specify both range values of jquery ui slider to max value as shown below, it becomes locked (The handles can't be adjusted anymore).

```
$("#slider_color").slider({ 
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    step: 1,
    values: [ 0, 10 ]
});

$('#click').on('click', function(){
    $("#slider_color").slider({values: [10, 10]});
});
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/0wr127c5/)

How can I avoid such behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old issue and it is fixed in newer versions of jquery-ui library.
But, if anyone still using an old version and cannot change it due to some project-specific reasons, there is a workaround that I found:

just

```
$("#slider").slider( "destroy" );
```

then create a new slider with your both max values. Not perfect solution, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known [bug](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9046), which is in fixed state with milestone set to `1.12.0`. Hopefully this will be fixed with that version.

Until then take look at the [commit related to the fix](https://github.com/lams1986/jquery-ui/commit/3a6feb7caf7fd7d8d63c268380fabf5b17bab254)